# Special characters problems in wordpress powered site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, character-encoding

Hey guys I'm having an issue because of some script a client wants to include in her wordpress site. The problem is I have to use a special charset for it to work properly, otherwise I have problems with the "áéíóú" characters. This is the code:

```
<script>

        var bae_bgcolor= "#FFFFFF";
        var bae_width="370";
        var bae_cantidad="3";
        var bae_showhead15=1;
        var bae_bgcolorhead15="#B8CDD6";
        </script>
        <style type=text/css>
        <!--
          .ib_fecha15 { font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; color: #606060}
          .ib_titulo15 { font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #606060; text-decoration:none;}
          .ib_head15 { font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: #5A555A}
        -->
        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="application/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="http://www.infobae.com/adjuntos/noticias/0000015.js"></script>
```

Now that got it working but I'm having problems with the rest of the site and where there should be a "ú" I get a "Ãº" and where there should be a "ó" I get a "Ã³". I changed the configuration so that I have      in the header. I still have problems and now I can't even post something new which contains those characters.

If anyone has had these problems before, any help will be...well, helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not go utf-8 instead of latin? Anyway, make sure your actual source files are stored using the same encoding as you tell the browser to use (in the header etc).

Comment: everything is in the same charset and switching to latin1 was what first solved the javascript box problem.

Comment: So all files are stored in iso-8859-1, the header says to use that, and all javascript files are too? When I open http://www.infobae.com/adjuntos/noticias/0000015.js notepad++ claims its encoded in ANSI, not iso-8859-1

Comment: but I overwrite it with         <script language="javascript" type="application/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="http://www.infobae.com/adjuntos/noticias/0000015.js"></script>

Comment: I think that the charset attribute specifies what encoding the remote file is _using_, not what you want to convert it to. Try to set it to the same encoding as you save the file in.

Comment: It won't work like that, The only way in which it will work is if the script is set to ISO-8859-1 and the file UTF-8

Comment: it works, but there's a catch. Wordpress post editor won't let me save anything with characters like  ñ ¿ á é í ó ú. So whenever I try to update a post or write something new which includes one of those, the thing won't save changes

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I include a piece of JavaScript with accented characters, I alwyas send it through [HTML Encode and Decode on Strictly Software](http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode), which would convert `á` into `&aacute;`.

It can be done on the fly but I've had difficulties saving the accented characters before. In those cases, I take the original script, run the text through the program on that link and re-save the file.

Comment: That would be alright in most cases but the thing is that the .js in the remote server is updated by that server every couple of hours, so I should actually script a crontab or something so it downloads the .js again every 10 minutes or so.